# How to prove that a curve is characteristic? (PDE's)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I'm having problems proving that a curve is characteristic, in PDE's

Assume that $r(t)$ is a parametrized curve on XY plane.
If $F(r(t)) = r'(t)$, we say that that parametrized curve is a characteristic curve.

Now, I don't know that $r(t)$ or $F(r(t))$ are…

I have an example for you:

$xUy - yUx = 0$

And I must find the solution that contains the curve $x = 0$; $U = y^2$

Altough I know how to find a solution, it says here that the curve mentionated earlier is characteristic and therefore it has an infinite amount of solutions.

So my questions are:

- Why does a characteristic curve have infinite solutions in an ODE? (maybe I'm asking that because I don't know very well the geometric meaning of it...). And why does a non-characteristic curve only has 1 solution?
- How can I prove that in the concrete example that I mentionated?

EDIT: I'm editing some stuff because my previous question may not be very clear.

Answer (score 1):

As $dU = U_x dx+U_y dy=0$ we have

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{U_x}{U_y} = -\frac xy
$$

so

$$
y dy + x dx = 0
$$

is the equation of a generalized characteristic curve or

$$
x^2+y^2= C
$$

NOTE

The constant $C$ characterizes a parametric family of circles (infinite possibilities).